# Sort Objects by Boolean values in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, boolean, enumerable

My apologies if this has been answered before or is obvious...did some searching here and on the Goog and couldn't find an answer.

I'm looking to sort an array of Providers by price and whether they are a preferred_provider? (true or false)

For instance in `array p of Providers`...

```
p1.price == 1, p1.preferred_provider? == false
p2.price == 2, p2.preferred_provider? == true
p2.price == 3, p3.preferred_provider? == true
```

I would like to p.sort_by and get:

```
[p2 p3 p1]
```

IAW

```
p.sort_by {|x| x.preferred_provider?, x.price }
```

does not work and gets...

```
undefined method `<=>' for false:FalseClass
```

Any suggestions on better ways to approach this problem?

Comment: Actually, you almost had it: p.sort_by {|x| [x.preferred_provider? ? 0 : 1, x.price]} .

Comment: Ah...nice.  refactoring candidate.  Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most languages provide sort functions that accept [comparators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparator) for this sort of thing.  In Ruby, this is just array.sort:

```
p.sort {|a, b| if (a.preferred_provider? == b.preferred_provider?
               then a.price <=> b.price
               elsif a.preferred_provider?
                    1
               else -1
       }
```

Comment: This logic doesn't return the correct order, but it put me on the right path using a.preferred_provider? == b.preferred_provider? and reversing 1 and -1.

thanks

Comment: Oops, of course you'd want to use == there (fixed now).  To elaborate a bit, the closure should return a positive number if a comes after b, a negative number if a comes before b, and 0 if they are equal for sorting purposes.  That way, an easy implementation for sorting numeric values is {|a,b| a - b}.

Answer (score 3):

You could define a `<=>` on the `Provider` class to do what you want, and then sort using the `Array.sort` method (rather than `Enumerable.sort_by`). Here's a definition of `<=>` that I whipped up:

```
class Provider
  def <=>(other)
    if preferred_provider?
      if other.preferred_provider?
        @price <=> other.price
      else
        1
      end
    else
      if other.preferred_provider?
        -1
      else
        @price <=> other.price
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Then, if you have your array `p`, you could just do `p_sorted = p.sort`.

(Note that I haven't tested this code, so there may be a few errors, but I think it serves to demonstrate the idea.)

Comment: This would work but the other solution was more appropriate for my problem for reasons I didn't state in the original question.  Thanks ...much appreciated.